# SQLite MissingFormatArgumentException

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm following a SQLite tutorial on Android, and is now stumped.
Help is greatly appreciated! :)

My code is to create a database representing Kitchen Inventory, then adding/deleting items accordingly.
Class I used:
KitchenItem - representation of a kitchen inventory item
KitchenDbHelper - extends SQLiteOpenHelper, to create the DB
KitchenDataSource - does the actual adding/deleting items on DB
KitchenInventoryActivity - setting the layout and intializing KitchenDataSource

But when I try to run the KitchenInventoryActivity, I get an exception:
Exception Ljava/util/MissingFormatArgumentException; thrown while initializing LKitchenDbHelper;
Thais is just the part in onCreate() where I new a KitchenDataSource.
I want to capture more logs, but unfortunately I can't add logs to the constructor. :(
I believe most of the code is irrelevant, but will still post the codes below.
Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Code of the KitchenDbHelper as below:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

//creates the DB
public class KitchenDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "kitchen.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_KITCHEN = "kitchen";

    //columns in database
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_CATEGORY = "category";
    public static final String KEY_ITEM = "item";
    public static final String KEY_AMOUNT = "amount";


    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_STATEMENT = 
            String.format("CREATE_TABLE %s ( %s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, %s TEXT,     %s TEXT, %s TEXT;", 
                          TABLE_KITCHEN,
                          KEY_ID,
                          KEY_CATEGORY,
                          KEY_AMOUNT);

    public KitchenDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_STATEMENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_KITCHEN);
        onCreate(database);
    }

}
```

Code of the KitchenItem:

```
import android.util.Log;

//this will be used as entries into KitchenDB
public class KitchenItem {
    //TODO: this will probably be modified in the future
    private long id;
    private String category;
    private String itemName;
    private String amount;

    public KitchenItem() {

    }

    public KitchenItem(int id, String category, String itemName, int amount) {
        this.id = id;
        this.category = category;
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.amount = Integer.toString(amount);
    }

    public KitchenItem(String itemName, int amount) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.amount = Integer.toString(amount);
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = Integer.toString(amount);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Log.d("KITCHEN", "toString in KitchenItem");
        return "itemName";
    }
}
```

Code of the KitchenDataSource:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;


public class KitchenDataSource {
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private KitchenDbHelper dbHelper;
    private String[] allColumns = {KitchenDbHelper.KEY_ID, 
                                     KitchenDbHelper.KEY_CATEGORY,
                               KitchenDbHelper.KEY_ITEM,
                               KitchenDbHelper.KEY_AMOUNT};

    public KitchenDataSource(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new KitchenDbHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public KitchenItem addItem(KitchenItem item) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KitchenDbHelper.KEY_CATEGORY, item.getCategory());
        values.put(KitchenDbHelper.KEY_ITEM, item.getItemName());
        values.put(KitchenDbHelper.KEY_AMOUNT, item.getAmount());

        long insertId = database.insert(KitchenDbHelper.TABLE_KITCHEN, null, values);

        Cursor cursor = database.query(KitchenDbHelper.TABLE_KITCHEN, 
                                       allColumns, 
                                   KitchenDbHelper.KEY_ID + " = " + insertId, 
                                   null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        KitchenItem newKitchenItem = cursorToKitchenItem(cursor);
        cursor.close();

        return newKitchenItem;
    }

    public KitchenItem getItem(int id) {
        Cursor cursor = database.query(KitchenDbHelper.TABLE_KITCHEN, 
                             new String[] {allColumns[0], allColumns[1], allColumns[2], allColumns[3]},
                             KitchenDbHelper.KEY_ID + "=?", 
                             new String[] {String.valueOf(id)},
                             null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        KitchenItem item = new KitchenItem(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), 
                                       cursor.getString(1), 
                                       cursor.getString(2),
                                       Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));

        cursor.close();

        return item;
    }

    public List<KitchenItem> getAllItems() {
        List<KitchenItem> itemList = new ArrayList<KitchenItem>();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(KitchenDbHelper.TABLE_KITCHEN, 
                                   allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            KitchenItem item = cursorToKitchenItem(cursor);
            itemList.add(item);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();

        return itemList;
    }

    public int updateItem(KitchenItem item) {       
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KitchenDbHelper.KEY_CATEGORY, item.getCategory());
        values.put(KitchenDbHelper.KEY_ITEM, item.getItemName());
        values.put(KitchenDbHelper.KEY_AMOUNT, item.getAmount());

        return database.update(KitchenDbHelper.TABLE_KITCHEN, values, KitchenDbHelper.KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(item.getId())});
    }

    public void deleteItem(KitchenItem item) {
        long id = item.getId();
        database.delete(KitchenDbHelper.TABLE_KITCHEN, 
                    KitchenDbHelper.KEY_ID + " = " + id,
                    null);
    }

    private KitchenItem cursorToKitchenItem(Cursor cursor) {
        KitchenItem item = new KitchenItem();
        item.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        item.setCategory(cursor.getString(1));
        item.setItemName(cursor.getString(2));
        item.setAmount(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));

        return item;
    }
}
```

Last but not least, the KitchenInventoryActivity:

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class KitchenInventoryActivity extends ListActivity {
    private KitchenDataSource dataSource;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("Kitchen", "KitchenInventoryActivity onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.kitchen_inventory_activity);

        dataSource = new KitchenDataSource(this);
        Log.d("Kitchen", "dataSource initialized");
        dataSource.open();

        List<KitchenItem> itemList = dataSource.getAllItems();
        ArrayAdapter<KitchenItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<KitchenItem>(this, 
                                                                      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                                                                      itemList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onClick(View clickedButton) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayAdapter<KitchenItem> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<KitchenItem>)getListAdapter();
        KitchenItem item = null;
        switch(clickedButton.getId()) {
        case R.id.add:
            //TODO: using a preconstructed item for now, will need to add user input
            KitchenItem tempItem = new KitchenItem("Pizza", 5);
            item = dataSource.addItem(tempItem);
            adapter.add(item);
            break;
        case R.id.delete:
            //TODO: just deleting the first item for now, will need to add selection
            if(getListAdapter().getCount() > 0) {
                item = (KitchenItem)getListAdapter().getItem(0);
                dataSource.deleteItem(item);
                adapter.remove(item);
            }
            break;
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        dataSource.open();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        dataSource.close();
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CREATE` statement has five replacement characters (`%s`), but you only have four variables... I assume you simply forgot `KEY_ITEM`:

```
String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT);", 
               TABLE_KITCHEN,
               KEY_ID,
               KEY_CATEGORY,
               KEY_ITEM,
               KEY_AMOUNT);
```

Also, I changed `CREATE_TABLE` to `CREATE TABLE` and added the missing `)`.
Lastly, Android requires the Primary Key to have the name `"_id"`, it won't except `"id"`...